# Find the integrable function $g:[0,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ in order to satisfy $\int_{0}^{x} t\cdot g(t) dt=x+x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have found $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}+2$ but it doesn't satisfy for $x=0$ , that is needed.

I also tried to define the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}+2$, with $ x>0$ and $ x\leq b$, $g(0)=0$.

Is that possible and if not how do i solve this problem?

Can we use Upper and Lower sums to solve it? (Riemann definition)

Comment: Why do you think that such a function $g(x)$ exists? Where did this problem originate?

Comment: The deleted answer by @gt6989b is good. It shows that _if_ such a $g$ exists, it must be $g(x)=2+\frac{1}{x}$. But then that $g$ is not integrable on $[0,b]$, so you can conclude no such $g$ exists.

Comment: But if we make the g discontinious close to x=0 so that g is well defind to [0,b]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$
\int_0^xt\,g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=x+x^2
$$
Then, for $x\ge0$,
$$
x\int_0^x|g(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\ge x+x^2
$$
which implies
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^x|g(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\ge\lim_{x\to0}\,(1+x)=1
$$
However, if $g(t)$ were integrable, 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^x|g(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t=0
$$
Therefore, no integrable $g$ can satisfy the equation.

Comment: Don't you need $g\ge 0$?

Comment: @user251257: I replaced $g$ by $|g|$ to take care of that

Comment: I like this answer because it shows that no Lebesgue integrable function exist either (+1).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. Indeed, suppose it exists. Then
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x t \cdot g(t) 
 \ \mathrm{d} t = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1+x = 1$$
hence $g(x) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ asymptotically as $x \to 0^+$.

This implies that $g$ is not integrable.

Comment: is g integratable for (0,b]?

Comment: the first equality is only valid, if you assume the limit of $xg(x)$ exists at $0^+$.

Comment: There is no difference between integrable in $[0,b]$ or in $(0,b]$.

Comment: Can we prove that is not integratable with the Riemann definition of an integral?(Upper sum , Lower sum)

Answer (score 1):

By differentiating both sides of $\int_{0}^{x} t\cdot g(t) dt=x+x^2$ and applying the Leibniz rule, we deduce that

$$ xg(x) = 1 + 2x$$

Here, let $g(x) = 2 + f(x)$. Then we are left with
$$xf(x) =1$$
Now this has the solution $f(x) = \frac 1x$ which is not good as Crostul pointed out. However, there is a *second solution* to this equation if you are willing to introduce distributions, namely

$$f(x) = -\delta'(x)$$

Hence $g(t) = 2- \delta'(t)$ is a distributional solution of your equation.